Data duplication or async on-demand oriented communication on microservices
In our current microservice, we store the data that doesn't belong to us and we persist them all through external events. And we use these duplicate data (that doesn't belong to us) in our actual calculation but I've been thinking what if we replace this duplicate data with async webclient on-demand calls with resilience fallbacks? Everywhere we need the data, we'll call the owner team through APIs. With this way, we'll set us free from maintaining the duplicate data because many times inconsistency happens when the owner team stop publishing the data because of an internal error. In terms of CAP, consistency is more important for us. We can give the responsibility of availability to the data owner team. For why not monolith counter argument, in many companies, there are teams for each service and it's not up to you to design monolith. My question, in this relation, is more about the general company-wide problem. When your service, inevitably, depends on another team's service, is it better to duplicate a data or async on-demand dependency?

Do you want a CP or AP system? Either you have inconsistencies, or you have unavailability as the downstream system isn't able to call the upstream system

(Generally, with microservices you want AP and inconsistencies, because the nature of microservices causes far more failure points to be tolerated than a monolithic architecture)

Consistency is more important for us. We can give the responsibility of availability to the data owner team.

Then why have microservices? Build a monolith, and query the database directly in a traditional view/stored procedure architecture.

But in many companies, there are teams for each service and it's not up to you to design monolith. My question, in this relation, is more about the general company-wide problem. When your service, inevitably, depends on another team's service, is it better to duplicate a data or async on-demand dependency?

and there is no single answer. It is a choice. Do you want a system that is available but inconsistent, or one that suffers regular outages, but is linearizable. Neither is inherently  'better'

I see. So you're saying that both options are applicable? I asked the question to assure that what I was thinking was not dummy or stupid solution :)

Resiliency is very difficult. Consider if the availability with no resiliency measures beyond not using the data requested/erroring would be acceptable. If so, synchronous should be fine. If not? Think long and hard about second and third order impacts of resiliency measures. Retries can increase overall failure rate in some scenarios.

I was also thinking after all the resilience precautions, if the async client still cannot get the data, put the data to the dead letter queues to retry later. With this way, no data would be lost. Would you agree?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
